# ListSelectionListener of NScrollTable

Tags: java, swing, events, event-handling, jtable

I have a table which has all the student details that I have entered. It is on left side of my screen. And in right side I have another panel with text fields which displays the student details based on the selection in the table. And we can modify those details also. To store the modified details I have added a button called 'post'

But the problem here is when I change some student details and without clicking on 'post' if I directly choose some other student in the table. Then 
before doing selection of that student I need to display a warning message.

And I have a class `StudentTable` which extends `ScrollPane` and implements `ListSelectionListener`. And I have another class called `StudentController` which also implements ListSelectionListener. And I am creating my table using `StudentTable` class and added listSelectionListener as `StudentController`. And I have overrided `valueChanged()` in both the classes i.e., `StudentTable` and `StudentController`. But as per my new requirement I have to call only `valueChanged()` of `StudentController` and from there I need to stop the call to `StudentTable`. So is there any way to stop that event like `consume()`

Anyone has an idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Didn't you add `ListSelectionListener` to the model of your table?

Comment: Somehow I can not understand why you've implemented `ListSelectionListener` in both `StudentTable` and `StudentController`. Why both of them are listening for the same `JTable`? And now you want to consume events that caught by one of them. It's somehow hard to find out what the real problem is. Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ListSelectionListener` to the `SelectionModel` of your table, and then every time the selection changed, check for the status of the data and the `post` button. If that wasn't posted the data, show the warning.

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            // TODO check here for your data, if changed and not posted, show warning

        }
    });
```

Comment: Ok but then I need to stop that event. I have updated my description. please look into it once